# How to prevent user from submitting text that already exists in a remote api?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am creating a VueJS app that contains a list of names called `divisions`. The user can submit a new name for a division and can also update a division name. The names of the divisions are received from a remote api and any edits made are then also sent to the api via a `PUT` request. This works well.

**However, the problem is how can I prevent a user from submitting a division name that *already exists*?**

I have a parent component (named `Divisions.vue`) that contains a GET request like so:

```
  methods: {
    async getAllDivisions() {
      try {
        this.divisions = (await ApiService.getAllDivisions()).data
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    }
  },
```

Here is how I have my code set up in a file called `DivisionEdit.vue`

**Template HTML:**

```
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmitUpdate">

    Division Name:
    <input type="text" v-model="division.division" />
    <button type="submit">
      Update Division
    </button>

</form>
```

**Script section:**

```
data() {
    return {
      division: {
        division: '',
        division_id: null
      },

methods: {
    onSubmitUpdate() {
    ApiService.updateDivision(this.division)
  }
}
```

And I have the **api service** code like so in `apiService.js`:

```
 updateDivision(division) {
    return this.getApiClient().put('/Divisions', division)
  }
```

Comment: does getApiClient have a `get` method? if so use it to get the item before using `post` method, if found then send error. note `put` should only update, is the issue someone overwriting existing or does `put` also add items?

Comment: You can do a `GET` request to fetch the divisions you already have and compare it on the fly in the app, or add a validation in the API's `PUT` endpoint to check and see if you already have the division before saving. If you do, throw an error

Comment: i updated my code to include a parent component where I am doing a GET request, i had forgotten to add that to my question.

Comment: @Edrian, ok, how can I compare it on the fly?

Comment: You can do an API call onChange if the field to check if the current input is already made. If this is too much, you can use some debouncing techniques to limit the rate in which the API calls are made. By this, I mean grouping the calls per a set amount of time like 500ms and after that waiting time, initiate a single request with it being the latest one of the debounced API calls.

Comment: Unless each user has it's own unique set of divisions you should prevent double names on the server, not the client. Reason? What if user 1 and 2 submit the same division at the same time? The server can prevent a double in this case, the client can not.

Comment: @fredrik, thanks for your feedback -- i won't have to worry about the user submitting double at the same time because there will only be a total of around 4 users that are allowed to make these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have all the divisions in the parent component, you can pass that as a props to child component

And in the child component before onSubmitUpdate, you can have two approaches here

> 1) you can disable the update button by default, and have validation
>   for the input division by adding @input event -> check division if
>   already exist, if not enable the button

```
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmitUpdate">

    Division Name:
    <input type="text" v-model="division.division" @input="divisionExists" />
    <button type="submit" :disabled="btnDisable">
      Update Division
    </button>

</form>

In Script: 

props: {
  divisions: Object,
},
data() {
    return {
      division: {
        division: '',
        division_id: null
      },
      btnDisable: true,
   }
}
methods: {
    divisionExists() {
      if (this.divisions.map(x => x.division).includes(this.division.division)){
        this.btnDisable = true
      } else {
        this.btnDisable = false;
      }
    },
    onSubmitUpdate() {
    ApiService.updateDivision(this.division)
  }
}
```

> 2) You can dirrectly add a condition in the onSubmitUpdate method to
>   check if the edit division is already exist it will not trigger update
>   api

```
onSubmitUpdate() {
if (!this.divisions.map(x => x.division).includes(this.division.division)){
            ApiService.updateDivision(this.division)
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the first approach. But, if a lowercase version of the same name is input by the user (ABC vs abc), it will still be submitted. How to validate this?

Comment: you can use this.division.division.toLowerCase(), to convert division to lowercase and check with divisions, Do accept aand upvote this answer

Comment: I tried: `if (this.divisions.map(x => x.division).includes(this.division.division.toLowerCase()))` but didn't work. I'll upvote and accept answer.

Comment: Use like this, the condition id            if (this.divisions.map(x => x.division).includes(this.division.division.toLowerCase()) || this.divisions.map(x => x.division).includes(this.division.division.toUpperCase()))

Comment: yes thanks! have another question but i'll make another post for that.